# Using a key from a for loop in django

Tags: django, for-loop

I have an array of arrays that I am trying to put into a table. It's something that works easily in PHP but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Django. I want to do something like this:

```django
{% for o in test %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ test.row{{o}}.test1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ test.row{{o}}.test2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ test.row{{o}}.test3 }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Exactly how looks `test`? Can you provide some sample data, together with expected output?

Comment: I want it to say {{test.row1.test1 }}{{test.row1.test2}}{{test.row1.test3}} etc...

Answer (score 0):

for an array like this :

random_array = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]

in python you should use

array[1][0] to acces the number 4

in django templating language it goes like this :

{{ random_array.1.0 }}

update :

```
<table>
{% for row in array %}
    <tr>
    {% for i in row %}
        <td>{{ i }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: I'm aware. I want to call it in a loop not have to write it out for every row.

Comment: you can do it like this : 
    {% for row in array %}
        {% for i in row %}
            {{ i }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

Comment: That is somewhat helpful, I'm getting the right count but it is only showing the first variable... maybe I need to use {% cycle %} or something?